# Black stains on oak after rain

Tags: wood, woodworking

I have made a DIY mailbox from oak wood boards a year ago.
But recently after heavy rains the oak turned black at the grains, looking like this:

[image: oak turned black at grains]

I did cover the oak with couple of coats of stain and a couple of coats of spar urethane to protect it.
However somehow that did not work.

Here's some close ups on what happened to the wood:
[image: oak turned black at grains - closeup1]
[image: oak turned black at grains - closeup2]
[image: oak turned black at grains - closeup3]

Questions:

- Any ideas on what exactly happened? My understanding was that oak by itself is resistant of the moisture, and with additional staining and spar urethane I was expecting it to last long.
- Is there any restoration that can be done here?

One suspicion that I have is that the metal sign (755 lakemead) has added to this - last year it wasn't there yet and mailbox survived the rain season without issues; this year with the sign on - this happened. I read somewhere that stainless steal on oak can react when moisture added. Curious if anyone can confirm that is this problem based on pictures.

Comment: That's what oak does when it gets wet. Unless you  manage to perfectly seal every  edge and penetration (and maintain that seal over time) it's inevitable. It's why oak isn't commonly used for outdoor things.

Comment: When water penetrates oak it reacts with the high tannin content within oak, resulting in ‘blackening’.  https://www.wood-finishes-direct.com/blog/what-everyone-should-know-about-finishing-oak/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the science behind this (chemists, please chip in!) but I would agree with the point about the presence of metal (particularly iron?).

For a few years now I've been making stuff out of some old oak fence posts that a friend of mine was throwing out.  Anywhere that metal fixings were in the wood was stained black.[image: black staining in oak due to fixings]
The fact that the worst stained boards are directly below the sign would, imho, lend weight to that.